# 'phonegap'/'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova

Ok I had phonegap installed and running since July this year, it wasn't an easy installation on windows but I managed it. However today I decided to update node, cordova and phonegap due to an issue with the phonegap CLI on my iphone.

I can now no longer use phonegap or cordova....
NPM at the cmd prompt is recognised but not phonegap or cordova.
If I echo the path env variable I get this:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x8 6)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files\AuthenTec TrueSui te\;C:\Program Files\AuthenTec
>   TrueSuite\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS C lient\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x8
>   6_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Wi
>   ndows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files  (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Mana gement Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine C omponents\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components
>   \DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\P rogram Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\ ;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO
>   Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startu p Setting
>   Tool;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Pr
>   ogram Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program
>   Files (x86 )\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\R oxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Roxio 2010\OEM\AudioCore\ ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platf orm
>   Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Pr ogram Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\ VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C :\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSV
>   N\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program File s (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Roaming\n
>   pm\node_modules\ant\ant\bin;C:\mobile\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\pla
>   tform-tools;C:\mobile\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\tools;C:\mobile\apa
>   che-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Ro aming\npm

My temp and tmp env vars are:

> C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Local\Temp

This directory does exist I've checked `"C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Roaming\npm"`
Beneath this directory are phonegap and cordova folders

> C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap
>   C:\Users\Connie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova

But if I type cordova or phonegap at the command prompt I get:
c:\mobile\Projects\vtfood>cordova
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> c:\mobile\Projects\vtfood>phonegap

'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any ideas anyone.... I have searched and tried various suggestions but nothing seems to work for me. :(
Thanks

Comment: Ok fixed it myself... reinstalled both cordova and phonegap through NPM using npm install -g cordova and same for phonegap. Seems happy for now...